# A question about $f(x)\equiv 0$

Tags: integration, integral-equations

If $f(x) \in C(-\infty+\infty)$, $\;g(x)=f(x) \int_0^x f(t)\,dt\,$ and $\;g(x)$ is monotone-decreasing in $(-\infty,+\infty),$

Prove:$f(x)\equiv 0$.

It is easy to get $g(0)=0$,and I'm thinking about proving $g(x)\equiv 0$,then $f(x)\equiv 0$ follows.

But I havn't any ideas to prove $g(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: Aren't "$g(x)$ is monotone decreasing" and $g(x)\equiv 0$ logically disparate?

Comment: @abiessu it is monotonically decreasing,not strictly decreasing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: Hmm.  How about, if $g(0)=0$ is easy, would it be easy to show $g(0+a)=0$ for any given $a$?

Comment: @abiessu yup,I tried,and failed.

Comment: Derivative of both sides using product rule and fundamental theorem of calculus for right side? We know g'(x) <= 0 everywhere. That, combined with the fact that a negative times a negative is positive MAY (or may not) help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let

$$F(x) := \int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$$

Then we have

$$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2} F(x)^2\right).$$

Since $g$ is assumed to be monotonically decreasing (non-strictly), we have $g(x) \geqslant 0$ for $x < 0$ and $g(x) \leqslant 0$ for $x > 0$. Hence we have

$$\frac{1}{2} F(x)^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{2} F(0)^2$$

for $x < 0$ as well as for $x > 0$. But since $F(0)= 0$, it follows that $F\equiv 0$. From that, $f \equiv 0$ follows easily.

Comment: I don't understand why "$g$ is assumed to be monotonically.....implies $F\equiv 0$" can you explain more it?

Comment: I know that if $g$ is non-increasing, so by definition for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that if $x\leq y$, so $g(x)\geq g(y)$. Now, in particular if $y=0$, so we have $\forall x\leq 0: g(x)\geq 0$ and $\forall x\geq 0: g(x)\leq 0$.

Comment: But, I don't understand why that implies $\frac{1}{2}F^{2}(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}F^{2}(0),\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and why that join $F(0)=0$ implies $F\equiv 0$, can you explain me?

Comment: @Ramanujan Since $g$ is non-increasing and $g(0) = 0$ it follows that $g(x) \geqslant 0$ for $x \leqslant 0$, and $g(x) \leqslant 0$ for $x \geqslant 0$. That means $x \mapsto F(x)^2$ is non-decreasing for $x \leqslant 0$ and non-increasing for $x \geqslant 0$. Thus $F(x)^2 \leqslant F(0)^2$ for all $x$. But $F(0) = 0$, so $F(x)^2 \leqslant 0$ for all $x$. But as a square of a real number we also have $F(x)^2 \geqslant 0$, thus $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to prove by contradiction that

if $\;x_0\;$ is a real number and if $\;f\;$ is a continuous function on $\;\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;$ such that $\;\int_\limits{x_0}^x f(t)dt=0\;\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;$ then
$f(x)=0\;\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:**

If there were $\;x^*\in\mathbb{R}\;$ such that $\;f\left(x^*\right)\ne0\;$, without loss of generality, we could suppose that $\;f\left(x^*\right)>0\;$.

By continuity of the function $\;f\;$, it would exist $\;\delta>0\;$ for which $\;f(x)>0\;\;\;\;\forall x\in\left[x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta\right]$.

Hence $\;\;\int_\limits{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} f(t)dt>0\;.\color{blue}{\quad{(*)}}$

On the other hand we get that

$\int_\limits{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta} f(t)dt=\int_\limits{x_0}^{x^*+\delta} f(t)dt-\int_\limits{x_0}^{x^*-\delta} f(t)dt=0\;,\color{blue}{\quad{(**)}}$

indeed, for hypothesis, it results that

$\;\int_\limits{x_0}^x f(t)dt=0\;\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

But $\;(**)\;$ contradicts $\;(*)\;$.

So it is not possible that there exists some $\;x^*\in\mathbb{R}\;$ for which $\;f\left(x^*\right)\ne0\;$, otherwise it would lead to a contradiction.

Hence,

$f(x)=0\;\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could anyone find a direct proof of the property I proved by contradiction?